# What does it mean for a closed walk and cycle to be of "odd length"?

Tags: graph-theory

What does it mean for a closed walk to be odd length? Is it counting the number of edges or vertices? Same for cycle.

Comment: It is the number of edges that are traversed. So if you go from $v_{1} \rightarrow v_{2} \rightarrow v_{3} \rightarrow v_{2}$ this is of odd length as you have traversed 3 edges, although one is repeated. For a walk to be closed simply end up at the same vertex you left from

Comment: @KeeranBrabazon - I think this is a good answer, maybe you should post it as such

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is the number of edges that are traversed. So if you go from $v_{1} \rightarrow v_{2} \rightarrow v_{3} \rightarrow v_{2}$ this is of odd length as you have traversed 3 edges, although one is repeated. For a walk to be closed simply end up at the same vertex you left from

Comment: Hi! I just started learning graph theory and I'm trying to gain an understanding of the edges concept. If the case of a closed walk, is the repeated edge counted in the length?